# How to add a member to team with email_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to rails and have stuck with a simple thing.

I have a method to add new members to the team:

```
  def add_member
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])
    @team.members << User.find(params[:user_id])
    redirect_to @team
  end
```

Every team has its author. I want the author to add a registered user to his team like this:

[image: add new member img]

My add button:

```
= link_to 'Add member', add_member_team_path(@team, user_id: user.id)
```

So if user with the email exists, he should be added to **@team.members**.
How to pass **user.id** from **email_field_tag** to my link button?

Sorry, if the question is silly. Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Now the code look this way:

Controller:

```
  def add_member_by_email
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])

    if @user.nil?
      render text: "No user found with that email" and return
    else
      @team.members << @user
      redirect_to @team
    end
  end
```

In my view:

```
= email_field_tag :user_email
= link_to 'Add to team', add_member_by_email_team_path(@team, email: :user_email)
```

In routes.rb:

```
  resources :teams do
    member do
      get :add_member_by_email
    end
  end
```

But keeps saying, there is no such user.

Comment: Are you assuming that a user with the given email address already exists?

Comment: Hello, @Undo. Yes, and if it doesn't exist just throw an error. But right now I just want  simply to add a user from the field.

Comment: If the user doesnt exist in the database, you will have to create one. Also are you using a form?

Comment: Hello, @jphager2! no, not a form. please, check my updated code to see my view.

Comment: Ok. So that is the reason you are not finding a user. On the web, forms are used to send user input to the server for processing.

Comment: @jphager2,  would you mind to share the code for this form? and if I change my method to post, it says 'No route matches [GET] "/teams/1/add_member_by_email'

Comment: See the answer that I just wrote. Forms normally send data via a POST. It may be beneficial for you to do some research on RESTful routes and the semantics of the HTTP verbs (GET PUT POST DELETE). That would be highly valuable information for you. Let me know if you continue to have an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view, use a form helper, which will render an html form tag:

```
= form_for User.new, url: add_member_path(@team) do |f|
  = f.text_field :email
  = f.submit "Add new member"
```

In the controller, you can access the user email like this:

```
params[:user][:email]
```

*Note: please excuse any typos or syntax errors in my post for now as I am writing this from the mobile app.*

Comment: it works!!! Thank you so much!! I'm about to read about all these GET PUT POST DELETE and forms. =)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the email address from your `email_field_tag`, and in your `add_member` action:

```
def add_member
  @team = Team.find(params[:id])
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if !user.nil?
    @team.members << user
    @team.save
    redirect_to @team
  else
    # Cannot find the user with the email address, do something here based on your design
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank a lot! I don't really to know, how to code email_filed_tag in my view. How to pass it user_email?

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to create a new path for this (and not just scab it on to the existing `add_member` path), something like:

```
def add_member_by_email
  @team = Team.find(params[:id])
  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:user_email])

  if @user.nil?
    render :text => "No user found with that email" and return
  end

  @team.members << @user
  redirect_to @team
end
```

And update your form:

```
= link_to 'Add member', add_member_by_email_team_path(@team)
```

Making sure that the email text field gives a `user_email` parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I also have a silly question, how to code this email_field_tag in my view? How to make it give user_email?

Comment: @Dair I think you want something like `= email_field_tag 'user_email'`. Try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: thanks! But it always renders "No user found with that email".

Comment: @Dair Could you edit your question to include the exact code you're using, in both the view and the controller?

Comment: please, check it now.

Comment: @Dair You mixed my code and the other answerer's code. Try using my code for the controller (change add_member_by_email to just add_member) and leave the view how it is.

Comment: changed it, but still not working. Also added my routes.rb just in case.

Comment: @undo you will have to also write the code for the form and change the route to a post. See my comment exchange on the OP's question.